# Is it good to include the type of a variable in its name?

Tags: naming

This is a naming convention question.

In C#, someone suggested that variables of type `List<T>` should be named as `listBlah` instead of just `blah`. Similarly for variables of type `Dictionary<keyT, valueT>`.
I think the reason is because we can guess the type of a variable by just looking at its name, without having to find where it is declared.

But when you create an object of a class with name "MyClass", what is some good practice to name the object (after the class' name)?

When you create a variable of primitive types such as `int`, `char`, `string`, `double`, what is some good practice to name it?

I guess this question is not just for C#, but also for other programming languages.

Comment: As a reader of somebody else's code, I don't want to see names which describe how the code works - that is not helpful at all to me.  I need names which describe the **intent** of the person who wrote the code. such as what requirement they're trying to satisfy, what behaviour or functionality they're implementing, and what something represents which can relate back to the requirements or behaviour.   I've never met a programmer who had difficulty figuring out how code worked just from looking at what it does, so there's no need for names and/or comments which state obvious information.

Comment: If you do this, would you rename it when you switch from a `List` to an `IEnumerable`? Doubtful... I'd recommend 2 things. A) Go read a bunch of [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) answers and B) Read [Joel Spolsky's seminal article on Hungarian Notation, Making Code Look Wrong](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/)

Answer (score 3):

This naming style has fallen out of favour, except in the case of Interfaces, which by convention in c# start with 'I'

Other related exceptions are things like Views, Controllers, ViewModels where the appropriate  word is sometimes appended to the class name.

Edit : Oh and 'Async' for async Methods is popular

Comment: The I for interface convention currently only infests C#.  It'd be nice if it didn't spread.

Comment: it is kinda nice to see the difference. maybe they could just make it a different colour instead

Comment: Interface, abstract, or concrete there is no reason the client using this dependency needs to know. Stop making me look at details I don't care about. Don't know. Don't want to know.

Comment: unless you try to new one up

Comment: Which you shouldn't be doing in a client anyway. Stop thinking it's ok to do it just because you can.

Comment: what about my complicated reflection scenario of super cleverness??!? you are sapping all the fun from programming

Comment: Well now I need a few minutes to have a good long cry.

Comment: .CryAsyncRememberToAwait() otherwise I might get confused

Comment: Ow ow ow ow! (but seriously we should be doing this in chat)

Comment: I'm gonna jump on the way too chatty bandwagon and say that @CandiedOrange is right here. I'm love C#, but I don't use the `IFoo` convention unless I'm working on a team.

Comment: I think the reason for the I is so you can have IMyClass and MyClass without having the think of a new name for one or the other

Comment: maybe we should have MyClass as the interface and IMyClass as the _I_MPLEMENTATION!

Comment: Ow ow ow! The problem is people don't take the time to think of better names than MyClass. Use the name to tell me something I should care about.

Comment: top tip: append a number so you know what they class is for. eg MyClass_23 if it start getting too long you can use 'hexidecimal' oe MyClass_56b

Comment: I should be able to tell that you're just messing with me. Unfortunately I have both graded student code and converted VB 6 code to .NET. My threshold of disbelief in bad code rivals the worst of [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/). So please, I beg you, say it aint so?